# status table join slows down query by 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.6

Got an issue with a fair few queries in our system that all rely on a status table (contains 3 rows)

```
CREATE TABLE `assessment_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Started` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Sequence` smallint(6) DEFAULT '1',
  `Archived` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `Archived` (`Archived`),
  KEY `Completed` (`Completed`),
  KEY `idAndcompleted` (`id`,`Completed`),
  KEY `idCompletedArchived` (`id`,`Completed`,`Archived`),
  KEY `idCompletedTitle` (`id`,`Title`,`Completed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data

```
id      Title           Completed   Started     Sequence    Archived
'1'     'Not Started'   '0'         '0'         '1'         '0'
'2'     'Started'       '0'         '1'         '2'         '0'
'3'     'Completed'     '1'         '1'         '3'         '0'
```

When running the query which has lots of other table joins but to this is:

```
select 
...
ass_s.Title AS `Assessment Section`
... 
from au
INNER JOIN assessment_status as_s ON au.idStatus = as_s.id
....
where as_s.Completed = 1
```

explain extended is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                                               key         key_len     ref         rows    filtered    Extra
'1' 'PRIMARY'   'as_s'  'ref'   PRIMARY,id,Completed,idAndcompleted,idCompletedArchived,idCompletedTitle'   'Completed' '1'         'const'     '1'     '100.00'    'Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

and the query takes about **12+seconds** to return

Yet if I switch it round to a subquery for title and where exists it runs in **0.6seconds**

```
select 
(select as_s.title from assessment_status as_s where au.idStatus = as_s.id and as_s.Completed = 1) AS `Status`
... 
from au
....
where exists (select as_s.Completed from assessment_status as_s where au.idStatus = as_s.id and as_s.Completed = 1)
```

explain extended is:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys                                                                   key         key_len     ref                 rows    filtered    Extra
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  as_s    eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,Completed,idAndcompleted,idCompletedArchived,idCompletedTitle        PRIMARY     4           fslcms.au.idStatus  1       100         Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  as_s    eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,Completed,idAndcompleted,idCompletedArchived,idCompletedTitle        PRIMARY     4           fslcms.au.idStatus  1       100         Using where
```

It's obviously still selecting on the same values, yet runs a hell of a lot faster as it's using where instead on const. The thing is, reading MySQL docs on ref const states it's because it's only using one value it treats it as a const, which is the fastest way!?

I'm quite new with MySQL, come from MSSQL and never come across such a small table that could cause such a big performance issue before... As you can see from the table create, I've even tried varied versions of the index to see if it helps.

Regards

Liam

Comment: Do you have an index on the other table, on `au (idStatus)`?

Answer (score 0):

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` and is an `INDEX`.  Don't re-declare `id` as `UNIQUE`.

Don't start an index with the `PRIMARY KEY`; it is likely never to be used.

Don't index flags; they are unlikely to be used.

So, I have just argued against all 6 secondary indexes, leaving only `PRIMARY KEY(id)`

There are only 3 rows in `assessment_status`, correct?  It is actually faster to do a table scan than to use an index.

Your first query seems to need to find the one row with `completed = 1`, then find the rows in `au` with `au.idStatus=3`, correct?

The `EXPLAIN` that you provide does not match the `SELECT`.  There are 2 tables in the select, but only one row in the explain??

Ditto for the second `EXPLAIN`.  But, there I see id=5 and id=3, implying that there are even more tables!  It *could* be that the order of tackling the tables was drastically changed; this could be a cause or clue of the timing differences.

How big is `au`?  The missing line in the `EXPLAINs` probably says that it will be a table scan, and gives an estimate of the number of rows.

Was the 12-second run tried twice?  I ask because the first run may have spent a lot of time fetching data from disk and the second would be running entirely from cached data in RAM.  This could also explain why the other query took only 0.6 sec.

If you are going to have the Question focus on a *portion* of the *real* query, then provide a shrunken test case that demonstrates it.  Else it *may not* be a valid shrinking, and we cannot necessarily help your *real* query.

Still, I will *guess* at what is going on.  The first query (I guess) had only one thing in the `WHERE` clause, a reference to as_s.  This tricked the Optimizer into deciding to *start* with that table.  But because of stuff not in evidence, some other table would be better to start with.  The second query seems to have taken that path; it could not start with `as_s` anyway.  A guess: there is no `WHERE` in the second query?

Comment: Hi Rick, I understand about the unneeded indexes, I have an issue with this on most of the tables, the previous manager decided nearly every column should have a single index??? (I've taken 4 minute queries down to a couple of seconds in some cases with optimisation) The au table has over 10million rows. Even when running the original query twice, it's still the same speed. There are 12 tables joined in this query which is why it comes back in a different place in the explain output. I was just confused how the join vs exists was so much slower when using the identical params to join on

Comment: @LiamWheldon - How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?@LiamWheldon

Comment: @LiamWheldon - 4m down to 2s -- something else happened when the indexes were dropped.  If you happen to have the `EXPLAIN` before and after, we might get to the bottom of it.

Comment: `JOIN` must find _all_ matching rows; `EXISTS` stops after finding _one_ row.  Some places it is called "semi-join".

Comment: Hi Rick, the 4m down to 2s was similar to this but not from removing indexes, was adding index with multiple columns as well as a few changes to narrow down data before joining. I'll stick with using the exists instead of join, just confused as to how such a small table on a join could slow it down so much yet other tables joined are fine. Thank you for responding to my query. The server is a RDS MySQL R3.2xlarge instance so has 61gb pool size is {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}